# Adding Edit Delete Button on VFpage

Tags: visualforce

I am an administrator trying out VF solutions; I have recently created a Visualforce page for a related list. I wanted to know if it is possible to add a edit/delete button in the page;

Here is the code I am using;

```
<apex:page standardController="Account_Plans__c">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock > 
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account_Plans__c.Key_Business_Initiative__r}" var="Key_Business_Initiative">
     <apex:column headervalue="Key Business Initiative"><apex:outputLink value="/{!Key_Business_Initiative.id}" target="_blank">{!Key_Business_Initiative.Name}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
     <apex:column value="{!Key_Business_Initiative.Account_Plan_Name__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!Key_Business_Initiative.Budget__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!Key_Business_Initiative.Champion_Name__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!Key_Business_Initiative.Initiative__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Key_Business_Initiative.Status__c}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to know if it is possible to add a edit/delete button in the page

The short answer is **Yes**. You can add any type of button you want on your Visualforce page as long as you have those actions available in your standard or custom controller. What you need here is to utilize [apex:commandButton](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandButton.htm).

You can refer to these links to get started on this topic:

- [Using Standard Controller Actions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm)
- [Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller.htm)
- [Input Data Using Forms Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/visualforce_fundamentals/units/visualforce_forms)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Will check this out.